# JavaScript Code to Detect Time a Process Took

Tags: javascript

So in my JavaScript file I'm trying to get it to detect how long an encryption/decryption took to occur and I'm getting it linked but the time is off quite a bit this is the code,

```
 var stop = new Date();
 var time = (stop-start) % 1000;
 if(time < 10) var ms = "00"+time;
 else if((time < 100) && (time >= 10)) var ms = "0"+time;
 else var ms = time;

 var s = Math.floor((stop-start) / 1000);

 if(document.forms['timer'].elements[0].checked == true)
 document.forms['timer'].elements[1].value = s+":"+ms;
 else document.forms['timer'].elements[1].value = "";
```

Which gives me answers like this 1327851955:962 as far as time it took when most of the time I'm sure it took less then a second, so if you don't mind could someone please explain how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

if you need it only for debugging use the Google Chrome Dev Tools you have few really nice methods;

`console.time('encryption')` where you want to start measuring the time and `console.timeEnd('encryption')` where you want to finish it.

You can also use some other great console tools like for example the profile method

`console.profile('encryption')` -> `console.profileEnd('encryption')` then go to the Profiles tab to be able to debug the CPU performance of your code and find any bottlenecks and places for improvement

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what your code is trying to acheive but you can time the amount of time it takes to do something  like this:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

//insert a call to do your encryption/decryption here..

var endTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log("The encryption/decryption took: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms.");
```

Comment: I must be doing it wrong I put it around the code but it gets Undefined:undefined as an answer, just a quick question because it is an option when I use it I should place the var startTime right after IF and right before the end correct?

Comment: Just put the `startTime` before you do anything you want to test the time it took.  By the way - `start` is not defined in the code you posted.